# sharepoint 2007 webpart question

Tags: 2007, web-part, visual-studio, wss-3.0, user-controls

I created a user control in visual studio I want to deploy to sharepoint 2007. This is my first one and I created the project using the repository pattern and POCO. Does sharepoint support this type of webpart implmentation or does all the logic have to be in the code-behind of the user control? The web part deployed successfully (dll in the GAC) but it is not available as a web part in the site. When I try to force it through SPD, the form errors out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) for creating Web Part project in Visual Studio...

Once you installed WSPBuilder, inside Visual Studio you will have WSPBuilder Project Templates, from there select required template... It will create WSP file for you, and you can deploy the WSP easily to get the Web Part!

Give it a try, it should solve all your problems!

Comment: I should have mentioned I was using wsp builder. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I wasn't using WSPBuilder. when I created a new WSPBuilder project I was able to create the user control and deploy it to the SP server. Therefore, I am marking yours as the answer also. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I was thinking, WSPBuilder is quite straight forward... No problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend you try [SmartPart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/) which is a codeplex project that allows you to host any ASP.NET web user control as a SharePoint web part.

Comment: Now that I look at the name of the original web part (developed by my predecessor), which mine is a modification of, it was named "MySmartPart" in SharePoint. I have a sneaking suspicion he used SmartPart :). Thanks!